# how it's work `ReadonlyArray` property in typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have the snippet code:

```
let a: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let ro: ReadonlyArray<number> = a;
a[0] = 8;

console.log(ro); //expext to be [1,2,3,4] not ok
console.log(a);//expext to be [8,2,3,4] ok
```

when i change Array `a`the `readonlyArray ro` is changed? why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're creating `ro` from `a` itself, both `ro` and `a` will have the same reference in memory, so whenever you change either of them, the other one will take effect of the other one.

### How to create an array from each other without passing the reference?

- You can use `.slice()`

  ```
  let a: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let ro: ReadonlyArray<number> = a.slice();
  a[0] = 8;

  console.log(ro); //expext to be [1,2,3,4] ok
  console.log(a);//expext to be [8,2,3,4] ok
  ```
- You can pass it by spread syntax.

  ```
  let a: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let ro: ReadonlyArray<number> = [...a];
  a[0] = 8;

  console.log(ro); //expext to be [1,2,3,4] ok
  console.log(a);//expext to be [8,2,3,4] ok
  ```
- You can use the `Array.from()` method, which makes a shallow copy of the existing array

  ```
  let a: number[] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  let ro: ReadonlyArray<number> = Array.from(a);
  a[0] = 8;

  console.log(ro); //expext to be [1,2,3,4] ok
  console.log(a);//expext to be [8,2,3,4] ok
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Create a copy using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or Spread operator

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let ro = Array.from(a); // [...a]
a[0] = 8;

console.log(ro);
console.log(a);
```

For readonly, try using [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let ro = [...a];

Object.freeze(ro);

a[0] = 8;
ro[0] = 8;

console.log(a);
console.log(ro);
```